# R gives strange error with ggplot2 expression: object 'rversion' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I encountered this error in Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, Rstudio 0.97.551 , R 3.1.0.
I suspect this is an error that has to do with the system environment or rstudio, but I am providing all the details just in case.
I am plotting a panel of plots using facet_grid. I have an irreproducible error when I use the following expression using ggplot2

```
censored_plot <- ggplot(aes(x=lcdm.breaks,y=value,color=diag_groups),
    data=subset(stats.df, test.type %in%
        c("kruskal","levene.hov","anova.homosk","anova.heterosk")))+
    facet_grid(side~test.type)+geom_line()
print(censored_plot)
```

The error is

```
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'rversion' not found
Graphics error: Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'rversion' not found
```

By irreproducible I mean I can repeat  the same expression and not get that error.
<s>For example, previously in the same session,</s>

```
censored_plot <- ggplot(aes(x=lcdm.breaks,y=value,color=diag_groups),
    data=subset(stats.df, test.type%in%   
        c("lillie","kruskal","anova.homosk","anova.heterosk")))+        
    facet_grid(side~test.type)+geom_line()

print(censored_plot)
```

I got the desired plot

```
censored_plot.2 <- ggplot(aes(x=lcdm.breaks,y=value,colour=diag_groups),
    data=subset(stats.df, test.type%in% 
        c("levene.hov" ,"wilcox.less", "wilcox.less.holm.corr" , "wilcox.greater.holm.corr")))+ 
    facet_grid(side~test.type)+geom_line()
print(censored_plot.2)

Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'rversion' not found
Graphics error: Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'rversion' not found
```

Ok, that wasn't the perfect example. so I had the following expressions later in the session:

```
> censored_plot.3 <- ggplot(aes(x=lcdm.breaks,y=value,color=diag_groups),
                           data=subset(stats.df, 
                                       test.type%in% c( "t.less", "t.less.holm.corr", "t.greater.holm.corr" )))+                          
                   facet_grid(side~test.type,drop=TRUE)+geom_line()
> print(censored_plot.3)

Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'rversion' not found
Graphics error: Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'rversion' not found
```

followed by

```
> censored_plot.3 <- ggplot(aes(x=lcdm.breaks,y=value,color=diag_groups),
                           data=subset(stats.df, 
                                       test.type%in% c( "t.less", "t.less.holm.corr", "t.greater.holm.corr" )))+                          
                   facet_grid(side~test.type,drop=TRUE)+geom_line()
> print(censored_plot.3)
```

No error. I get the desired plot

In case somebody else gets this error: You are not alone.

edit:

these are the combinations of subsetting that caused the error.
I will use %str1% to denote 
`ggplot(aes(x=lcdm.breaks,y=value,color=diag_groups),` for making the code shorter

```
> censored_plot.3 <-  %str1% data=subset(stats.df, 
                                       test.type%in% c( "t.less", "t.less.holm.corr", "t.greater.holm.corr" )))+                          
+   facet_grid(side~test.type,drop=TRUE)+geom_point()
> print(censored_plot.3)
##No error

> censored_plot.3 <-  %str1% data=subset(stats.df, 
                                       test.type%in% c( "t.less", "t.less.holm.corr", "t.greater.holm.corr" )))+                          
   facet_grid(side~test.type,drop=TRUE)+geom_line()
> print(censored_plot.3)
##No error

> censored_plot <-  %str1% data=subset(stats.df,
                                     test.type%in% c("lillie","kruskal","anova.homosk","anova.heterosk")))+        
                           facet_grid(side~test.type)+geom_line()
> print(censored_plot)
##No error 


> censored_plot.2 <-%str1% data=subset(stats.df, 
                                     test.type%in% c("levene.hov" ,"wilcox.less", "wilcox.less.holm.corr" , "wilcox.greater.holm.corr")))+ 
                   facet_grid(side~test.type)+geom_line()
> print(censored_plot.2)
#Error


> censored_plot.3 <- %str1% data=subset(stats.df, 
                                       test.type%in% c( "t.less", "t.less.holm.corr", "t.greater.holm.corr" )))+                          
                   facet_grid(side~test.type,drop=TRUE)+geom_line()
> print(censored_plot.3)
## No error

censored_plot.lil <-  %str1% data=subset(stats.df,
                                     test.type%in% c("lillie")))+        
   facet_grid(side~test.type)+geom_line()
> print(censored_plot.lil)
# No error

 censored_plot <-  %str1% data=subset(stats.df,
                                     test.type%in% c("kruskal","levene.hov","anova.homosk","anova.heterosk")))+        
                           facet_grid(side~test.type)+geom_line()
> print(censored_plot)
#Error


censored_plot.2 <-  %str1%  data=subset(stats.df, 
                                     test.type%in% c("wilcox.less", "wilcox.less.holm.corr" , "wilcox.greater.holm.corr")))+ 
                   facet_grid(side~test.type)+geom_line()
> print(censored_plot.2)
# Error



> censored_plot.3 <- %str1% data=subset(stats.df, 
                                       test.type%in% c( "t.less", "t.less.holm.corr", "t.greater.holm.corr" )))+                          
                   facet_grid(side~test.type,drop=TRUE)+geom_line()
> print(censored_plot.3)
#Error

censored_plot.3 <-  %str1% data=subset(stats.df, 
                                       test.type%in% c( "t.less", "t.less.holm.corr", "t.greater.holm.corr" )))+                          
                   facet_grid(side~test.type,drop=TRUE)+geom_line()
> print(censored_plot.3)
#no error

> censored_plot.2 <-  %str1% data=subset(stats.df, 
                                     test.type%in% c("wilcox.less", "wilcox.less.holm.corr" , "wilcox.greater.holm.corr")))+ 
                   facet_grid(side~test.type)+geom_line()
> print(censored_plot.2)
#no error

> censored_plot.lil <-  %str1% data=subset(stats.df,
                                     test.type%in% c("lillie")))+        
   facet_grid(side~test.type)+geom_line()
> print(censored_plot.lil)
> 
#no error

> censored_plot <-  %str1%  data=subset(stats.df,
                                     test.type%in% c("kruskal","levene.hov","anova.homosk","anova.heterosk")))+
                           facet_grid(side~test.type)+geom_line()
> print(censored_plot)
# error

> censored_plot.lil <-  %str1% data=subset(stats.df,
                                     test.type%in% c("lillie")))+        
   facet_grid(side~test.type)+geom_line()
> print(censored_plot.lil)
#no error

> censored_plot.lil <-  %str1% data=subset(stats.df,
                                     test.type%in% c("lillie")))+        
   facet_grid(side~test.type)+geom_line()+scale_y_continuous(limits= c(0,1))
> print(censored_plot.lil)
#no error
```

I was able to get the plots I wanted at the end. But still, I have no clue what is going on and why I got the opaque error message.

Comment: Those are not the same expressions!

Comment: It appears that you did change the subsetting. Are you sure if it's exactly the same isn't not reproducible?

Comment: these are the combinations of subsetting that caused the error.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem until just now

I found this link, suggesting an Rstudio-core problem
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200649626-Graphics-error-when-executing-a-second-plot-from-a-R-script-using-recent-R-3-0-2-patched-versions

I upgraded my RStudio and that resolved the issue

(I'm using Windows, but the RStudio core is cross-platform.
My new RStudio version is RStudio-0.98.507.exe)

Comment: Ok I will upgrade and see if I can still cause the problem. Not sure if I can replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way that may fix a

`Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object`

error is to just quit RStudio and start it again.