# Autoplot error when using ggcyto (Bioconductor) package: 'ggplot.data.frame' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running R-3.5.0 and RStudio 1.1.423 on Windows 7. I had to use our corporate installer for both programs, so I did not download the installer .exe files and am also limited in having the most recent version of the software.

I am trying to use the Bioconductor project FlowCore and ggcyto package to plot flow cytometry events. In the beginning this worked quite well, but recently (and I have no idea if I even changed anything) I cannot plot my flowframes using autoplot. Here's the example from the ggcyto documentation:

```
library(flowCore)
library(ggcyto)
data(GvHD)
fs <- GvHD[subset(pData(GvHD), Patient %in%5:7 & Visit %in% c(5:6))[["name"]]]
autoplot(fs, x = "SSC-H")
```

which results in

```
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) :
object 'ggplot.data.frame' not found
```

I noticed one strange thing: I cannot update the stringi package to the latest (I believe 1.2.3) version, only to 1.1.7.

It is suggested in this thread: [R gives strange error with ggplot2 expression: object 'rversion' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923902/r-gives-strange-error-with-ggplot2-expression-object-rversion-not-found)
that it is an RStudio problem. However, when running the same code in the R console without RStudio, I get the same error message.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the problem. Apparently I must have updated my packages and the latest ggplot2 release does not interact well with the ggcyto package.

A downgrade of ggplot2 to version 2.2.1 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem today running the most up-to-date R binaries and Rstudio version. I ended up using the package "flowViz" and the function: flowplot() to receive essentially the same result (just without the binning) as the autoplot() function of the "ggcyto" package utilized in the FlowCore Vignette. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Yes, indeed this function works. However, it can only be used for flowFrames and unfortunately does not handle flowSets.

Answer (score 0):

I am happy to report that this no longer fails in more recent R/BioC environments such as:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /n/apps/CentOS7/install/r-3.5.2/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /n/apps/CentOS7/install/r-3.5.2/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggcyto_1.10.2             flowWorkspace_3.30.2      ncdfFlow_2.28.1           BH_1.69.0-1               RcppArmadillo_0.9.400.3.0 ggplot2_3.1.1             flowCore_1.48.1           usethis_1.5.0             devtools_2.0.2           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1          mvtnorm_1.0-10      lattice_0.20-38     corpcor_1.6.9       prettyunits_1.0.2   ps_1.3.0            assertthat_0.2.1    rprojroot_1.3-2     digest_0.6.18       R6_2.4.0            plyr_1.8.4          backports_1.1.4     stats4_3.5.2        pcaPP_1.9-73        pillar_1.4.0        zlibbioc_1.28.0     rlang_0.3.4         lazyeval_0.2.2      data.table_1.12.2   Rgraphviz_2.26.0    callr_3.2.0         hexbin_1.27.3       labeling_0.3        desc_1.2.0          stringr_1.4.0       munsell_0.5.0       compiler_3.5.2      pkgconfig_2.0.2     BiocGenerics_0.28.0
[30] pkgbuild_1.0.3      IDPmisc_1.1.19      tidyselect_0.2.5    gridExtra_2.3       tibble_2.1.1        matrixStats_0.54.0  XML_3.98-1.19       flowViz_1.46.1      rrcov_1.4-7         crayon_1.3.4        dplyr_0.8.1         withr_2.1.2         MASS_7.3-51.4       grid_3.5.2          gtable_0.3.0        magrittr_1.5        scales_1.0.0        graph_1.60.0        KernSmooth_2.23-15  stringi_1.4.3       cli_1.1.0           fs_1.3.1            remotes_2.0.4       testthat_2.1.1      latticeExtra_0.6-28 robustbase_0.93-5   RColorBrewer_1.1-2  tools_3.5.2         Biobase_2.42.0     
[59] glue_1.3.1          DEoptimR_1.0-8      purrr_0.3.2         processx_3.3.1      pkgload_1.0.2       parallel_3.5.2      colorspace_1.4-1    cluster_2.0.9       sessioninfo_1.1.1   memoise_1.1.0
```